# How to downgrade gcc, g++, and gfortran?

Tags: gcc, c++, g++

I'm trying to install the package `mice` in Rstudio but the installation fails and shows the error `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran`. I note that there is no directory called `/usr/bin/ld` in my PC, but I have gfortran installed. I have never used `fortran` in my life but I suppose that gfortran compiles fortran code in the same way that gcc and g++ compiles `C` and `C++` code, respectively. As I heard that `R` is built on C and Fortran I decide to check if there is some incompatibility in the version of these compilers. Then I ran:

```
gcc --version
g++ --version
gfortran --version
```

The output was:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~16.04~ppa1) 7.4.0
g++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~16.04~ppa1) 7.4.0
GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 5.4.0 20160609
```

As it turns out, I have different versions installed. To solve this I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gfortran-4.9
sudo apt-get install --reinstall g++-4.9
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gcc-4.9
```

However, when I check again which version I have installed of each compile I still get the same output. In other words, none of the downgrades took effect.

Then I try to follow the instructions from the answer to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188341/how-can-i-force-an-older-version-of-g-if-i-have-a-newer-version). Thus I ran:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
```

This open a dialog screen that asks me to select which version of gcc I would like to use as default. I chose `4.9` and then I check again using `gcc --version` and it works fine. Great.

Nevertheless, when I ran the same command for g++ and gfortran I didn't have the same success. In fact, it turns out that g++ is no longer installed in my PC since the command `gcc --version` returns `bash: /usr/bin/g++: No such file or directory`. I didn't know what happened, but I guess that my configuration of g++ is related to that. That's my guess because g++ runs normally when I configure gcc again using the `7.4` version as default.

Regarding gfortran, my problem is a bit different. When I tried to change the default version the shell returns `error: no alternatives for gfortran`. Then I tried the gfortran installation again using:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gfortran-4.9
```

which returns:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gfortran-4.9 is already the newest version (4.9.4-2ubuntu1~16.04).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 408 not upgraded.
```

That's what I have tried until now. I have two questions: 1) Am I in the right way to solve this problem? (if not, what should I do?) 2) If this can solve my problem, how can I downgrade g++, and gfortran?

Comment: I solve this by running `sudo apt-get install r-base`